# resposive template with skel.js and asp.net mvc relative content

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, responsive-design

I am developing an asp.net mvc application and I use [this](http://html5up.net/minimaxing/) template for my app. For js and css resources, I use URL.Content helper method, but the problem is that css resources referenced by template loads only in home/index action and when I go to other action, browser consoles says that it cant find the resources.

Here is what I have in my _layout.cshtml:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.3.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/js/config.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/js/skel.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/js/skel-panels.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

<noscript>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="@Url.Content("~/css/skel-noscript.css")"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="@Url.Content("~/css/style.css")" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="@Url.Content("~/css/style-desktop.css")" />
</noscript>
```

Here is what I can see in chrome Element tab:

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/js/config.js"></script>
<script src="/js/skel.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style-desktop.css">
<script src="/js/skel-panels.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css"></style>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<noscript>

        &lt;link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/skel-noscript.css"/&gt;
        &lt;link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css" /&gt;
        &lt;link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style-desktop.css" /&gt;
    </noscript>
```

And here is the error I got from console in broswer:

```
GET http:///myapp/test/css/style-desktop.css 404 (Not Found) skel.min.js:1
GET http://myapp/test/css/style.css 404 (Not Found) skel.min.js:1
```

Comment: Hi found the answer just need to put relative address in config.js

Answer (score 3):

All you have to do is set the "prefix" in "_skel_config" obj. to the right path of your styles.

```
window._skel_config = {
    prefix: 'css/style',
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Alaasdk is right, most of similar templates using skelJS come with something like this:

```
window._skel_config = {
    prefix: '/css/style'
}
```

in their js/config.js file. So if you have controllers that handle URLs like this:

```
domain/users/10
domain/category/subcategory/article-slug
```

or similar, you only set it to relative URL like

```
prefix: '/css/style'
```

Answer (score 0):

The stylesheet links you have in your snippet are in a `<noscript>` block and only apply to users who have javascript turned off.

As @marcus33cz and @alaasdk point out, you set the relative path in config.js.

In the latest version of skel, you set it in init.js like this:

```
global: { href: '/css/style.css', containers: 1400, grid: { gutters: ['2em', 0] } },
desktop: { media: '(max-width: 1680px)', href: '/css/style-desktop.css', containers: 1200 },
// and so on for all of your stylesheets
```